# 'Impermanence' during vipassana practice

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, vipassana, impermanence

Thoughts stopped when seen them. Either happy or sad feelings of mind disappears by seen them. Is this impermanence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is impermanence, at the experiential level. You are getting the hang of the fact that experiences come and go, and they get affected by mere looking at them.

There is also impermanence at a deeper or subtler level, where every sensation becomes ripply or vibratory - that can be seen when mind is trained to see impermanence at a deeper/subtler level.

edit: I don't know a better term to use than ripply to describe it, anyways my usage of the term comes from [Shinzen Young's meditation manual](https://www.shinzen.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/WhatIsMindfulness_SY_Public_ver1.5.pdf), page 41. (A beautiful illustration of meditation path up to the arising and passing away stage can be found in pages 40-45)

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain? Is it because it doesn't answer the question or because of some other reason like it differs from your view of what impermanence is...

Comment: I did not downvote the answer. I suspect it might be due to using the words *"ripply or vibratory"*. I think what is meant, is that things are transitory and in a constant flux, is that correct? Anyway, I think its a good answer and I upvoted it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct... transitory, constant flux are good terms to describe it. Just that they don't capture the feeling of shaking one's identity or sense of continuity that generally happens as one observes impermanence at a deeper level, so the use of word "ripply". But looks like that doesn't make it any clearer..

Comment: For a practitioner of insight meditation it makes sense, but for a non-practitioner or beginner it might not. Thanks for adding the elaboration with a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Impermanence is when you see something arise and then pass. So yes, when you see thoughts and then see them stop, that is impermanence. Same is with feelings.

Answer (score 0):

During Vipassana, you will see the impermanence in all Sankhara.
Seen impermanence in Jhana also an aspect of Vipassana.